# How to run a venv in the docker?

Tags: python, docker, python-venv

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7 AS builder
RUN python3 -m venv /venv

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN /venv/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /home/sokov_admin/www/bot-telegram

COPY . .

CMD ["/venv/bin/python", "./bot.py"]
```

When I run the docker image I have this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "/venv/bin/python": stat /venv/bin/python: no such file or directory:
> unknown.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: You don't need a virtualenv within the container.

Comment: You also don't really need a "builder" container unless you have some C code being compiled

Comment: But if I dont use a virtualenv my python script doesnt see dependencies.

Comment: @OneCricketeer
But if I dont use a virtualenv my python script doesnt see dependencies.      
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'`

Comment: You still need to run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, just without using `venv/bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you show doesn't need any OS-level dependencies for Python dependency builds.  That simplifies things significantly: you can do things in a single Docker build stage, without a virtual environment, and there wouldn't be any particular benefit from splitting it up.

```sh
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["./bot.py"]
```

The place where a multi-stage build with a virtual environment helps is if you need a full C toolchain to build Python libraries.  In this case, in a first stage, you install the C toolchain and set up the virtual environment.  In the second stage you need to `COPY --from=...` the entire virtual environment to the final image.

```sh
# Builder stage:
FROM python:3.7 AS builder

# Install OS-level dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential
    # libmysql-client-dev, for example

# Create the virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Install Python dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# If your setup.py/setup.cfg has a console script entry point,
# install the application too
# COPY . .
# RUN pip3 install .

# Final stage:
FROM python:3.7 # must be _exactly_ the same image as the builder

# Install OS-level dependencies if needed (libmysqlclient, not ...-dev)
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...

# Copy the virtual environment; must be _exactly_ the same path
COPY --from=builder /venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Copy in the application (if it wasn't `pip install`ed into the venv)
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Say how to run it
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./bot.py"]
```

Comment: Is it executable (you may need to run `chmod +x bot.py` outside of Docker)?  Does it start with a "shebang" line, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`?

Comment: how does that work.? Why dont we need to activate the venv? Is it because its first in the path so when running a pip command, it will use the one from the venv ?

Comment: Correct.  The other thing that's interesting here is if you just run a binary or wrapper script directly out of the virtual environment – `./venv/bin/pip install foo` – that will automatically "activate" the virtual environment and install packages into `venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`.  Putting the virtual environment `bin` directory at the front of the path is helpful but you don't _need_ to `. venv/bin/activate`.